# How to run a function a bunch of times with different arguments in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to make a bunch of plots simultaneously using a function which I wrote in R to make one plot at a time. My function calls multiple arguments including a FUN argument which specifies which plotting function should be used for each sample.

I would like to read a table/dataframe into R and then run the same function on each row, where each row specifies the arguments for that run.

My function looks like this:

```
printTiff <- function(FUN, sample, start, end) {
  tiff(paste(sample,".tiff", sep=""), compression="lzw",width=892,height=495)
  g <- FUN(sample,start,end)
  dev.off()
}
```

I have a table with a column for FUN, sample, start and end, where each row should end up a different tiff. I've tried using do.call, but I can't seem to get it right. I have several hundred samples, so I'd like to avoid changing the arguments with each run.

Sample of table:

```
      FUN      sample    start      end
1 T7Plots   sample343 27520508 27599746
2 C9Plots   sample347 27522870 27565523
3 C9Plots   sample345 27535342 27570585
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `match.fun` to look up the function by its name, then you can use it.

```
printTiff <- function(FUN, sample, start, end) {
  FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
  paste(sample, FUN(start), end);
}

table <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
FUN      sample    start      end
T7Plots   sample343 27520508 27599746
C9Plots   sample347 27522870 27565523
C9Plots   sample345 27535342 27570585
")


T7Plots <- `-`
C9Plots <- function(x) 1/x
```

Then we can use mapply like @alexis_laz

```
mapply(printTiff, table[,1], table[,2], table[,3] ,table[,4])
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `get` to match a function. Use `match.fun` which is designed *expressly* for this inside a function.

Comment: @SimonO101 Updated answer to use match.fun

Answer (score 3):

Use `mapply`:

```
    mapply(printTiff, table[,1], table[,2], table[,3] ,table[,4])
```

Comment: I'm trying to use mapply as you suggested, but it won't read the first column as a function name. It keeps returning with       'test[, 1]' is not a function, character or symbol          any ideas?